# Traverse JSON object to build JSTree

Tags: javascript, json, jstree, traversal

I have a JSON object and want to traverse it so that it matches the structure of JSTree:

Original JSON:

```js
{
 "analogBasebandProcessorBoardType": "Test_BOARD",
 "tuners": {
  "tuner1": "RFE_MAIN",
  "tuner2": "MAX93"
 },
 "allowedSoftConfigs": ["30-16", "30-29", "10-22"]
}
```

It should look like this:

```js
{
    'core': {
      'data': [
      {
          'text': 'analogBasebandProcessorBoardType',
          'children': 
                      [
                        {
                          'text': 'Test_BOARD'
                        }
                      ]
      }, 
      {
          'text': 'tuners',
          'children': 
                      [{
                        'text': 'Tuner1',
                        'children': 
                        [{
                          'text': 'RFE_MAIN'
                        }]
                      },
                       {
                         'text': 'Tuner2',
                         'children': 
                         [{
                           'text': 'MAX93'
                         }]
                       }
                      ]
       },

       {
          'text': 'allowedSoftConfigs',
          'children': 
                [
                        {
                            'text': '30-16'
                         }, 
                         {
                            'text': '30-29'
                         },
                         {
                            'text': '10-22'
                         }
                ]
        },

      ]
    }
  }
```

I think the only way to solve this is traversing. I have tried it but it is not exactly what I want, but I think I am not very far away from the solution.

This is the JSON that is being generated:

```js
{
 "core": {
  "data": {
   "analogBasebandProcessorBoardType": {
    "text": "analogBasebandProcessorBoardType",
    "children": [{
     "text": "Test_BOARD"
    }],
    "tuners": {
     "tuner1": {
      "text": "tuner1",
      "children": [{
       "text": "RFE_MAIN"
      }],
      "tuner2": {
       "text": "tuner2",
       "children": [{
        "text": "MAX93"
       }],
       "allowedSoftConfigs": {
        "0": {
         "1": {
          "2": {
           "text": "2",
           "children": [{
            "text": "10-22"
           }]
          },
          "text": "1",
          "children": [{
           "text": "30-29"
          }]
         },
         "text": "0",
         "children": [{
          "text": "30-16"
         }]
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

My code alway uses the "name" as the key for the data-array. It would be correct if there is no key. But I am not sure where this behavior is caused.

It would be great if someone could take a look on it as I don't know how to solve it.
Here is the complete code but it is easier to view in jsfiddle i think:

```js
//function to add something to objects with a string path
function assign(obj, prop, value) {
    if (typeof prop === "string")
        prop = prop.split(".");

    if (prop.length > 1) {
        var e = prop.shift();
        assign(obj[e] =
                 Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[e]) === "[object Object]"
                 ? obj[e]
                 : {},
               prop,
               value);
    } else
        obj[prop[0]] = value;
}



$(function() {
  // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready

var tbjsonstring = '{ "analogBasebandProcessorBoardType": "Test_BOARD", "tuners": {  "tuner1": "RFE_MAIN","tuner2": "MAX93" }, "allowedSoftConfigs": ["30-16", "30-29", "10-22"]}';

var tbjson = JSON.parse(tbjsonstring);

var computedJSON = {
    'core': {
      'data': [
      ]
    }
  }
var path = "core.data";

console.log(tbjson);
(function traverse(o) {
var z = 0;
    for (var i in o) {
      data0 = {
                  'text': i,
             }
       data1 = {
                  'text': o[i],
             }      
      if(traversed == 1){
      console.log("traversed" + o[i]);
      // assign(computedJSON,path,data1);
        traversed = 0;
      }else{
     //   assign(computedJSON,path,data0);
      }       
     
      console.log('key : ' + i + ', value: ' + o[i]);

   //console.log(path);
   path = path+"."+i;
      z++;
      if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
        //going on step down in the object tree!!
        var traversed = "1";
        traverse(o[i]);
      }else{
      //key value pair, no children
      data = {};
      data = {
          'text': i,
          'children': [{
            'text': o[i]
          }]
      }
      assign(computedJSON,path,data);
      }  
    }
  })
  (tbjson);

//print to the console
console.log(JSON.stringify(computedJSON));





//This is the working json, computedJSON should looke like this:
  var jstreejson = {
    'core': {
      'data': [
      {
          'text': 'analogBasebandProcessorBoardType',
          'children': 
                      [
                        {
                          'text': 'Test_BOARD'
                        }
                      ]
      }, 
      {
          'text': 'tuners',
          'children': 
                      [{
                        'text': 'Tuner1',
                        'children': 
                        [{
                          'text': 'RFE_MAIN'
                        }]
                      },
                       {
                         'text': 'Tuner2',
                         'children': 
                         [{
                           'text': 'MAX93'
                         }]
                       }
                      ]
       },

       {
          'text': 'allowedSoftConfigs',
          'children': 
                [
                        {
                            'text': '30-16'
                         }, 
                         {
                            'text': '30-29'
                         },
                         {
                            'text': '10-22'
                         }
                ]
        },

      ]
    }
  }


//jstree initialization
  $('#jstree').jstree(jstreejson);
  $('#tbjstree').jstree(computedJSON);
  // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
  $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function(e, data) {
    console.log(data.selected);
  });

});
```

```html
The won't run in the stackoverflow-snippet-editor (even with loaded js/css files) so please visit jsfiddle for a working demo:
<a href='https://jsfiddle.net/dnffx4g8/6/' target='_blank'>JSFiddle Demo</a>
```

**jsfiddle-link:** https://jsfiddle.net/dnffx4g8/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterative an recursive approach for it, with a function who checks for array and object and iterates accordingly.

```js
function buildObject(source) {
    if (Array.isArray(source)) {
        return source.reduce(function (r, a) {
            if (a !== null && typeof a === 'object') {
                return r.concat(buildObject(a));
            }
            r.push({ text: a });
            return r;
        }, []);
    }
    if (source !== null && typeof source === 'object') {
        return Object.keys(source).map(function (k) {
            return {
                text: k,
                children: buildObject(source[k])
            };
        });
    }
    return [{ text: source }];
}

var data = { "analogBasebandProcessorBoardType": "Test_BOARD", "tuners": { "tuner1": "RFE_MAIN", "tuner2": "MAX93" }, "allowedSoftConfigs": ["30-16", "30-29", "10-22"], "PathValue": [{ "links": ["in1->GSES_1.in1", "GSES_1.out1->GSES_1.in1", "GSES_1.out1->out1_1"], "ParamFile": "IN1_OUT12.txt" }, { "links": ["in1->GSES_1.in1", "GSES_1.out2->GSES_2.in1", "GSES_2.out1->out1_2"], "ParamFile": "IN1_OUT52.txt" }] },
    result = { core: { data: buildObject(data) } };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
function buildObject(source) {
    if (Array.isArray(source)) {
        return source.map(text => ({ text }));
    }
    if (source !== null && typeof source === 'object') {
        return Object.keys(source).map(text => ({ text, children: buildObject(source[text])}));
    }
    return [{ text: source }];
}

var object = { analogBasebandProcessorBoardType: "Test_BOARD", tuners: { tuner1: "RFE_MAIN", tuner2: "MAX93" }, allowedSoftConfigs: ["30-16", "30-29", "10-22"] },
    result = { core: { data: buildObject(object) } };
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. The non-ES6-approach works best, but it does not work with objects in objects. I have updated the JSFiddle:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dnffx4g8/7/

The ES6-variant does not show childrens of a children. For compability-reasons I would prefer the non-ES6 variant but I don't know how to modify it that it works with objects. Could you help me out again?

Comment: @bademeister, please see edit in the first proposal.

Comment: Great, now it works as expected, thank you! I wonder that no one else had this problem with jsTree and own JSON-objects.

Comment: "PathValue": [{ "links": ["in1->GSES_1.in1", "GSES_1.out1->GSES_1.in1", "GSES_1.out1->out1_1"], "ParamFile": "IN1_OUT12.txt" }, { "links": ["in1->GSES_1.in1", "GSES_1.out2->GSES_2.in1", "GSES_2.out1->out1_2"], "ParamFile": "IN1_OUT52.txt" }]  <br/> This multi dim array of object is flatten to a single array.  Is there  a way to keep multi dimension array?

Answer (score 0):

Given an object named *data*, you could use this ES6 function:

```
var result = {
  core: {
    data: (function treeify(data) {
        return Array.isArray(data) ? data.map ( value => treeify(value) )
            : typeof data !== 'object' || data == null ? { text: data }
            : Object.keys(data).map(key => ({ text:key, children: [treeify(data[key])] }));
    })(data)
  }
};
```

Here is a snippet with your sample data:

```js
var data = {
 "analogBasebandProcessorBoardType": "Test_BOARD",
 "tuners": {
  "tuner1": "RFE_MAIN",
  "tuner2": "MAX93"
 },
 "allowedSoftConfigs": ["30-16", "30-29", "10-22"]
};

var result = {
  core: {
    data: (function treeify(data) {
        return Array.isArray(data) ? data.map ( value => treeify(value) )
            : typeof data !== 'object' || data == null ? { text: data }
            : Object.keys(data).map ( key => ({ text: key, children: [treeify(data[key])] }) );
    })(data)
  }
};

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

NB: I would not name your objects *tbjson* or *computedJson*, to avoid confusion with plain JavaScript objects. The term JSON is better reserved for the text notation.

#### Explanation of the Code

*treeify* is a recursive function. The value it returns depends on the data type of the argument that is passed to it:

- When it is an array (`Array.isArray()`) then the function is called recursively for each element (`treeify(value)`), and these results are assembled in a new array (the return value of `data.map()`) that is returned to the caller.
- When it is a non-object (as `null` is considered an object a separate test is needed for that), then the value is given to the `text` property of a new object which is returned to the caller (`{ text: data }`).
- When it is an object, the keys of that object are iterated (`Object.keys(data).map()`) and for each corresponding value the function is called recursively (`treeify(data[key])`). That result is put in an array and assigned to the `children` property of a new object, while the key is assigned to the `text` property of that same object. This is returned to the caller.

The result variable will start the calling chain for initialising the value of the `data` property.